# implementing quicksort and getting a bug I don't understand

Tags: python, algorithm, search, quicksort

I have 2 functions, a function that partitions an array and quicksort itself:

```
def partition(a, i, j):
    h = i+1

    for k in range(i+1, j):
        if a[k] < a[i]:
            a[h],a[k] = a[k],a[h]
            h += 1
    a[i],a[h-1] = a[h-1],a[i]

    return h 

# a is an array. After function call a[i..j-1] is sorted in increasing order
def quicksort(a, i, j):
    if j-i <= 1: return

    swap(a, i, j)
    p = partition(a, i, j)

    quicksort(a, i, p)
    quicksort(a, p, j)
```

This works for all the test cases I tried, that is I call quicksort(a, 0, len(a)) and the list a is sorted after.

I'm trying to change the pivot element. I want to use the last element of the array as the pivot instead of the first one (like in the implementation above). For that purpose I add the following line of code to the quicksort function just before the partition:

```
a[i],a[j-1] = a[j-1],a[i]
```

and everything breaks. The maximum recursion depth gets exceeded. I don't understand why it's happening and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` would drop into infinite loop with `p == 0`; switch `p` with `p-1`/`p+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given input `[1,2,3]`, it would drop into infinite loop with consistent `p`; switch `p` with `p-1`/`p+1`:

```
def quicksort(a, i, j):
    if j <= i: return

    swap(a, i, j)
    p = partition(a, i, j)

    quicksort(a, i, p-1)
    quicksort(a, p+1, j)
```

Comment: [1,2,3] works for the code without the swap. How can the swap mess this up?

Comment: write down the loop process in your paper :) @ÞórÓðinsson